# How to access an element of a 2D array in assembly?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

How to access an element of a 2D array in assembly? I found a few code examples, but they are using `edx` and `eax` registers, which are not supported by emu8086 (16-bit registers only).
I want to make variable t equal to the value of array[0][1] (t = 2).
What should I do?

```
.8086
.model small
.stack 100h

.data 

    t dw ?

    array   dw 1, 2, 3,
            dw 4, 5, 6,
            dw 7, 8, 9

.code 
    ; ax <- array[0][1]
    mov eax, DWORD PTR[array + 8] ; not working
    ; t <- ax
    mov t, eax ; t = 2
```

Comment: It’s not a 2D array. It’s just numbers after each other in a linear array. You just have to calculate the index into it.

Comment: Replace edx, eax with dx and ax, respectively. Those are just integer variables :)

Comment: well, it's not working with ax as well :( something's wrong in the code

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: 16-bit addressing modes can only use `[bx|bp] + [di|si]`, so `[dx + ax]` wouldn't assemble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to make variable t equal to the value of array[0][1] (t = 2).

The array is filled with words. The 2nd element on the 1st row is at offset 2 in the array.

```
mov ax, [array + 2]
mov [t], ax
```

Depending on the assembler the last line could read:

```
mov t, ax
```

---

Since you're working with `.model small`, did you setup the `DS` segment register?

If you change to `.model tiny`, you wouldn't need to setup any segment registers.

Comment: Oh, exactly. I've forgot about that, thanks a lot :)